# Google Charts - passing data as variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, xslt, charts, google-visualization

I am creating a report in a health application using google charts. Due to the way that the application works, I have to define the data for the chart in an XSL document and then use javascript to grab and use that data. I can't run the javascript inline within the XSL - the application blocks it.

The XSL works fine and gives me the following :-

```
<div id="mydata" style="display:none;">
        [{c:[{v: new Date(2020,3,21)}, {v:94.05}]},
         {c:[{v: new Date(2020,3,29)}, {v:94.3}]},
         {c:[{v: new Date(2020,4,5)}, {v:95}]},]
</div>
```

My javascript then looks like this:-

```
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  var mydata=$("#mydata").text()
  var mydata=mydata.replace("},]", "}]");
  var myconfig="{cols: [{id: 'Date', label: 'Date', type: 'date'},{id: 'Weight', label: 'Weight', type:'number'}],rows: " + mydata + "}"


function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(myconfig);



    var options = {
      title: 'Patient Weight',
      curveType: 'function',
      legend: { position: 'bottom' }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

The problem is that it doesn't work. I get :

```
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token c in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at gvjs_Li (jsapi_compiled_default_module.js:55)
    at new gvjs_L (jsapi_compiled_default_module.js:161)
    at drawChart (<anonymous>:8:20)
```

If I copy the value out of myconfig and paste it into the google visualisation it works perfectly.   This is the resultant myconfig variable:-

```
 cols: [{id: 'Date', label: 'Date', type: 'date'},{id: 'Weight', label: 'Weight', type:'number'}],rows: 
        [{c:[{v: new Date(2020,3,21)}, {v:94.05}]},{c:[{v: new Date(2020,3,29)}, {v:94.3}]},{c:[{v: new Date(2020,4,5)}, {v:95}]}]}
```

This is driving me mad .Please help!

UPDATE:

Finally cracked this!!

I put the cols definition into the DIV as well and put quotes around EVERYTHING, removed the "new" as suggested and finally it works!!

Comment: I think you have an extra comma near the end of the data defined in your div.

Comment: this is true, but the .replace in the JS removes it. Apologies - i pasted the wrong javascript (script now corrected)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this approach on occasion, here's what I've found.

the reason it works when you hard-code the data,
you're passing an object to the data table.

but when the data comes from XSL, it is a string.

first, all of the object keys must be wrapped in quotes.
second, you cannot use the `new` operator on the dates.
you must use google's [date string representation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datesandtimes#dates-and-times-using-the-date-string-representation)

try formatting the data as follows from the XSL...

```
[{"c":[{"v": "Date(2020,3,21)"}, {"v":94.05}]},
     {"c":[{"v": "Date(2020,3,29)"}, {"v":94.3}]},
     {"c":[{"v": "Date(2020,4,5)"}, {"v":95}]}]
```

---

note: about the comma, following is the xsl I use to prevent the last comma...

```
<xsl:if test="position() != last()">,</xsl:if>
```